# lettrine with image

Tags: lettrine

Working with `lettrine` in a probably not intended kind leads me to a problem.
When running the following example you can see that the two lines of text are not starting at the same position. Ugly! I hope and believe that there is a workaround to get a smart and LaTeX-like result.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}
\begin{document}
\lettrine{\tikz\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1ex,2ex);}{} This is just
a ridiculous test. This is just a ridiculous test. This is just a
ridiculous test. This is just a ridiculous test.
\end{document}
```

Remark: In my application there is no red rectangle but an opened book as a hint for a literature cross reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lettrine/doc/lettrine.pdf) of `lettrine`:

> `findent=<dimen>` (positive or negative)
>   controls the horizontal gap between the dropped capital and the
>   indented block of text (default=0pt);
>
> `nindent=<dimen>` shifts all indented lines,
>   starting from the second one, horizontally by
>   `<dimen>` (this shift is relative to the first line,
>   default=0.5em);

Then the following setting can be used, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}
\begin{document}
  \lettrine[
    findent=.5em,
    nindent=0pt
  ]{\tikz\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1ex,2ex);}{}% comment line end (space)
  This is just
  a ridiculous test. This is just a ridiculous test. This is just a
  ridiculous test. This is just a ridiculous test.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the fine manual. The solution works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You said, you will use image in lettrine. Then you need the following:

```
\lettrine[
    lines=2,
    lraise=0.05,   %% raises or lowers (for -ve value) image
    findent=.5em,   %% controls the gap between image and the text
    image=true]{example-image-a}{This}
```

Here the option `image=true` allows you to put an image (`example-image-a` here}. Note that the second argument contains `This` and to prevent this word from changing its font, you have to use

```
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}
\renewcommand{\LettrineTextFont}{\normalfont}
\begin{document}
\lettrine[
    lines=2,
    lraise=0.05,
    findent=.5em,
    image=true]{example-image-a}{This} is just
a ridiculous test. This is just a ridiculous test. This is just a
ridiculous test. This is just a ridiculous test.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like that?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5cm}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[nindent = 0em]{\tikz\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1ex,2ex);\,}{}This is just a ridiculous test. This is just a ridiculous test. This is just a
ridiculous test. This is just a ridiculous test.

\end{document}
```

[image]