# Adding a Letter to an Image in a Do-It-Yourself Lettrine

Tags: tikz-pgf, box, lettrine

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.25in}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\tikz\fill[black] (0,0) rectangle (5ex,7ex);\,}{} would like this box to be a lettered lettrine; more specifically, I would like it to contain a fitted-to-the-box, white, bold capital I. How may this be accomplished? Thank you.
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I add within the box a big, bold (white-colored) letter (such as *I*) in order to obtain a fairly respectable homemade lettrine? (I got this idea after looking at the post [lettrine with image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238651/lettrine-with-image) which does not show how to do this.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here, I use a simple `\colorbox` to contain the versal and then scale it to the desired size.  EDITED to handle descenders, such as capital `Q`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor,scalerel,stackengine}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.25in}
\fboxsep=1pt
\newcommand\my[1]{\scaleto{\colorbox{black}{%
  \textcolor{white}{\abovebaseline[0pt]{#1}}}}{7ex}\,}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my I}{} would like this box to be a
  lettered lettrine; more specifically, I would like it to contain 
  a fitted-to-the-box, white, bold capital I. How may this be 
  accomplished? Thank you.

\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my W}{ould} this work as I desire it?  Who 
  can say?  Let us give it the old ``college try'' and see what results.

\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my Q}{uestions} remain on the proper method
  to handle descenders.  In this case, I shift all letters up to sit
  fully upn the baseline, even if it means the ``Q'' gets diminished
  slightly in size.
\end{document}
```

[image]

This approach provides ample opportunity for customization.  For example, colors and versal font can easily be adjusted (I also increased `\fboxsep` by .5 pt, to contain the protruding points on `W`):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor,scalerel,stackengine}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.25in}
\fboxsep=1.5pt
\newcommand\my[1]{\scaleto{\colorbox{black!70}{%
  \textcolor{white}{\abovebaseline[0pt]{$\mathcal{#1}$}}}}{7ex}\,}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my I}{} would like this box to be a
  lettered lettrine; more specifically, I would like it to contain 
  a fitted-to-the-box, white, bold capital I. How may this be 
  accomplished? Thank you.

\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my W}{ould} this work as I desire it?  Who 
  can say?  Let us give it the old ``college try'' and see what results.

\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my Q}{uestions} remain on the proper method
  to handle descenders.  In this case, I shift all letters up to sit
  fully upn the baseline, even if it means the ``Q'' gets diminished
  slightly in size.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternately, with the `mathrsfs` package, defining the color as `red!50!black` and the versal as `$\mathscr{#1}$`.  Further, I reduce the versal height from 7ex to 6ex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor,scalerel,stackengine,mathrsfs}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.25in}
\fboxsep=1.5pt
\newcommand\my[1]{\scaleto{\colorbox{red!50!black}{%
  \textcolor{white}{\abovebaseline[0pt]{$\mathscr{#1}$}}}}{6ex}\,}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my I}{} would like this box to be a
  lettered lettrine; more specifically, I would like it to contain 
  a fitted-to-the-box, white, bold capital I. How may this be 
  accomplished? Thank you.

\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my W}{ould} this work as I desire it?  Who 
  can say?  Let us give it the old ``college try'' and see what results.

\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my Q}{uestions} remain on the proper method
  to handle descenders.  In this case, I shift all letters up to sit
  fully upn the baseline, even if it means the ``Q'' gets diminished
  slightly in size.
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SPECIAL SUPPLEMENT FOR BARBARA BEETON**

To address the dismay brought on by my handling of descenders like `Q` in the above approach, I felt compelled to remedy the situation.  It still requires a little manual intervention with the `Q`, both to extend the lettrine lines from 2 to 3, as well as to grow the vertical extent of the `Q` from the default `7ex` height to something larger (here `9ex`).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor,scalerel,stackengine}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.25in}
\fboxsep=1pt
\newcommand\my[2][7ex]{\scaleto{\colorbox{black}{%
  \textcolor{white}{\abovebaseline[0pt]{#2}}}}{#1}\,}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my I}{} would like this box to be a
  lettered lettrine; more specifically, I would like it to contain 
  a fitted-to-the-box, white, bold capital I. How may this be 
  accomplished? Thank you.

\lettrine[nindent = .4em]{\my W}{ould} this work as I desire it?  Who 
  can say?  Let us give it the old ``college try'' and see what results.

\lettrine[nindent = .4em, lines=3]{\my[9ex] Q}{uestions} remain on the
  proper method to handle descenders.  In this case, I increase the number
  of lettrine lines from 2 to 3, and I have modified \textbackslash my
  to take an optional argument length, to revise the height of the 
  encased letter.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking at those `$`s and thinking  when suddenly "An edit has been made to this post" and then they were gone. 

Comment: @DonHosek Actually, not.  Since `scalerel` works by default in math mode, I used the Stoopid convention of employing `$` delimiters to force the argument into text mode (regret #3716).  However, in this case, the `\colorbox` accomplishes text mode without the need for the `$` delimiters, so the delimiters were not *necessary*.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Thank you for this most helpful answer.

Comment: @mlchristians You are welcome.  I edited my answer to provide additional variants.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes Thank you kindly for the additional examples which are useful to my purpose.

Comment: Very nice, both the mechanism and the well illustrated answer.

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton.  That means a lot coming from you, a noted expert and stickler for detail.

Comment: Would you consider writing it up as a short note for TUGboat, or contributing it to the "Duckboat"?  I think other people would like it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'd be happy to, though it is kind of self-explanatory.  How should I format things (simple article class)?  Length desired?  BTW, I am in something of a hectic phase, as I will be retiring from federal service on 9/30.  If communicating via email is preferable, my recent package entries provide personal email, my older packages my USG email.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I felt the pressure.  I had to go back and address the issue of descenders like `Q`.

Comment: Hmmm.  With the Roman, the Q would look better with a third line cut out of the main text, the baselines matched with the second line, and the tail hanging below.  But I'm being mega-niggly here, and I'm afraid that would be a major project.  But I really couldn't bring myself to ignore it.  (As you quite fairly observed, I'm a fussbudget.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Please see the **SUPPLEMENT** to my answer, designed just for you.

Comment: Oh, that's great!  now the height above the top text line is uniform, and all the initials are all the same size.  (I'm ignoring the request to move this to chat.)