# Adding a Colored Frame to a Do-It-Yourself Lettrine

Tags: border, lettrine, colorbox, stackengine, frame

This question is an extension of the one posed a while back in [Adding a Letter to an Image in a Do-It-Yourself Lettrine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611290/adding-a-letter-to-an-image-in-a-do-it-yourself-lettrine)

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{imperialred}{RGB}{239, 38, 50}
\definecolor{deepskyblue}{RGB}{34, 154, 202}

\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.25in}
\fboxsep=2.25pt
\newcommand\my[2][7ex]{\scaleto{\colorbox{deepskyblue}{%
    \textcolor{imperialred}{\abovebaseline[0pt]{#2}}}}{#1}\,}
    
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE
\lettrine[nindent=.4em]{\bfseries\my I}{} would like add a frame (or perhaps, some other kind of a decorative border) around this this box.
  
\lettrine[nindent=.4em]{\my T}{he} commands of tcolorbox do not seem to be applicable here.
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

QUESTION: How may I add a colored frame of adjustable thickness (or perhaps, some other kind of decorative border) around the blue ``do-it-yourself'' lettrines?

Thank you.

Comment: \fboxrule5pt\fcolorbox{imperialred}{deepskyblue}{ ... }

Comment: @Fran Thank you for the comment; but perhaps, you might expand this as an answer. I'm sorry, but I cannot figure out where it goes in the code.

Comment: It is just change your `\colorbox{color1}`  by `\fcolorbox{color2}{color1}` (with  "f" of "f"rame for color 2) and, optionally,  you can add before `\fboxrule` to set the thickness of the frame to 5pt (or what you want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\fcolorbox` instead of `\colorbox` to add the a colored frame and \fboxrule` to set the thickness of this frame.

Out of the question, I set  `\lettrine` command to avoid use of  `\scaleto` or `\abovebaseline`: Not sure if it matches the desired format, but I hope that you can get the idea for a fine-tuning.  I also avoided the macros to make the example simpler and add some more dummy text to check that drop capital fit smoothly.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lettrine, lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{imperialred}{RGB}{239, 38, 50}
\definecolor{deepskyblue}{RGB}{34, 154, 202}
\begin{document}
\LARGE

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.6,lraise=.1,nindent=.5em]{\fboxsep5pt\fboxrule5pt\fcolorbox{imperialred}{deepskyblue}{\color{imperialred}I}}{} would add a frame (or perhaps, some other kind of a decorative border around this this box. \lipsum[1][1-4]

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=.6,lraise=.1,nindent=.5em]{\fboxsep5pt\fboxrule5pt\fcolorbox{imperialred}{deepskyblue}{\color{imperialred}T}}{he}  commands of tcolorbox do not seem to be applicable here.
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. At first, I was not able to replicate your lettrine displays, as they were much smaller and fell below the first sentence. Perhaps because I compiled your code with `lualatex` had something to do with it. Nevertheless, when I invoked the package `type1cm`---most everything seemed to work well, with the minor exception that I would need to shift the blue portion of the lettrine ever so slightly to the left to center it within the red frame. Do you have any idea how I might invoke such a shift so that the blue portion is "perfectly" centered? Yours seems fine

Comment: @mlchristians In this MWE, as is, or in your document? I also compiled this with `lualatex` and `type1cm` do not change the output at all, but it fix  the small lettrines obtained only with `pdflatex`  (same output, as far I see). Maybe you are really using "pdflatex"? Otherwise, your document must  have something else that change the output.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into it.