# Tweaking an Initfamily Do-It-Yourself Colored Lettrine

Tags: fonts, color, dimensions, lettrine, stackengine

The following code mimics Steven B. Segletes' answer to the question posed in [Adding a Letter to an Image in a Do-It-Yourself Lettrine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611290/adding-a-letter-to-an-image-in-a-do-it-yourself-lettrine):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{yfonts,xcolor,scalerel,stackengine,lettrine}
\definecolor{Blood}{RGB}{142,0,28}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{255,179,0}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in}

\fboxsep=1pt
\newcommand\mylettrine[2][2.75ex]{\scaleto{\colorbox{Blood}{%
  \initfamily\textcolor{Gold}{\abovebaseline[0pt]{#2}}}}{#1}\,}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\LARGE

\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.25,nindent=0.4em,findent=-0.6em]{\mylettrine{N}}{on} semper erat aestas.\\[30pt]
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.25,nindent=0.4em,findent=-0.6em]{\mylettrine{W}}{}\\[30pt]
\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.25,nindent=0.4em,findent=-0.6em]{\mylettrine{R}}{}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

As you can see, the lettrines are not all of uniform size---and `stackengine` seems to accommodate the various letter sizes quite nicely; however, a little "tweaking" is in order, as the `initfamily` lettrine letter that I am trying to add a background color to also contains decorative florishes that extend beyond the given letter, and consequently, outside of the colored box I am trying to "stack" the letter on.

I have tried adjusting the `\fboxsep` command various ways, but have seemingly made matters a little worse.

QUESTION: Is there a way to, and if so, how, may I uniformly adjust the colored background so that all of these `initfamily` decorative lettrines may appear reasonably centered on the colored background with all the jumping flourishes nicely contained within the squarish colored box?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean setting `\fboxsep=5pt`, because it interacts with the scaling? What does "worse" mean (in or out?)?

Comment: The centering is thrown off so that the decorative letter requires a greater vertical and horizontal, though not necessarily uniform, shift to be centered---if the colored box were big enough.

Comment: @Cicada The centering is thrown off so that the decorative letter requires a greater vertical and horizontal, though not necessarily uniform, shift to be centered---if the colored box were big enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a box command that uses a defined padding for each letter.

I just did these by eye.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{yfonts,color,lettrine}
\definecolor{Blood}{RGB}{142,0,28}
\definecolor{Gold}{RGB}{255,179,0}
\setlength{\textwidth}{3in}


\begin{document}

\newcommand\qqq[1]{{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\colorbox{Blood}{%
\sbox0{\color{Gold}\initfamily#1}%
\ifcsname Left #1\endcsname\kern\csname Left #1\endcsname\fi
\ifcsname Top #1\endcsname\ht0=\dimexpr\ht0+\csname Top #1\endcsname\relax\fi
\ifcsname Bottom #1\endcsname\dp0=\dimexpr\dp0+\csname Bottom #1\endcsname\relax\fi
\box0 %
\ifcsname Right #1\endcsname\kern\csname Right #1\endcsname\fi
}}}

\expandafter\def\csname Left A\endcsname{1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left B\endcsname{3pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left D\endcsname{.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left E\endcsname{.1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left I\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left J\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left M\endcsname{3pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left N\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left O\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left P\endcsname{.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left Q\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Left Y\endcsname{1pt}

\expandafter\def\csname Right C\endcsname{.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Right G\endcsname{.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Right H\endcsname{.1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Right L\endcsname{.1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Right P\endcsname{2pt}


\expandafter\def\csname Top A\endcsname{.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top B\endcsname{3pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top C\endcsname{3pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top D\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top E\endcsname{1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top F\endcsname{3.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top G\endcsname{3.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top H\endcsname{3pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top I\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top J\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top K\endcsname{3pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top L\endcsname{1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top M\endcsname{1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top N\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top O\endcsname{2.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top P\endcsname{2.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top Q\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top R\endcsname{2.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top S\endcsname{3pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top T\endcsname{3.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top U\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top V\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top W\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top X\endcsname{3pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top Y\endcsname{4pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Top Z\endcsname{3pt}

\expandafter\def\csname Bottom A\endcsname{1.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom B\endcsname{.1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom K\endcsname{.1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom M\endcsname{2pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom N\endcsname{.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom O\endcsname{.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom P\endcsname{1.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom Q\endcsname{.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom R\endcsname{1.5pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom U\endcsname{.1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom X\endcsname{.1pt}
\expandafter\def\csname Bottom Y\endcsname{.1pt}






% just for tests
\def\doqqq#1{#1: \qqq{#1}\par\doqqq}
\long\def\stopqqq#1\doqqq{}

\doqqq ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\stopqqq




\end{document}
```